# Скопировать файлы по шаблону на рабочий стол. PermissionError в shutil.copyfile()

Tags: python, shutil

Здравствуйте. Есть код, который собирает все файлы по шаблону и должен копировать их на рабочий стол:

```
import re
import os
import shutil

for papka in os.walk(r'C:\Program Files'):
    for pidpapka in papka:
        for x in pidpapka:
            if re.match(r'\D+[.][j][p][g]',x) != None:
                print(os.path.join(papka[0],x))
                a = os.path.join(papka[0],x)
                shutil.copyfile(r'a', r'C:\Users\Grzegorz\Desktop\1')
```

Но почему то выскакивает ошибка:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\Grzegorz\\Desktop\\1'
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: У меня на питон 3.5 проблем нет, добавьте версию к вопросу

Comment: gil9red, изменил вопрос, так как первоначальная проблема решилась

Comment: А как? Насчет проблемы доступа, запустите скрипт от администратора

Comment: gil9red, нужно было изменить название скрипта, так как он был под названием copy :). Открываю с правами администратора - не помагает

Comment: Странно, изменил shutil.copyfile на shutil.copy2 и все ОК

Comment: os.walk() неправильно у вас используется (она триплеты генерирует).

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы скопировать из `src` папки в `dest` рекурсивно все файлы, удовлетворяющие шаблону, можно задать `ignore` параметр для `shutil.copytree()`, чтобы пропустить неинтересные файлы:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import re
import shutil

def non_dir_or_jpg(path, names):
    return {name for name in names
            if not (os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path, name))
                    or re.fullmatch(r'\D+\.jpg', name))}

shutil.copytree('src','dest', ignore=non_dir_or_jpg)
```

Допустим содержимое `src` выглядит как:

```
src
├── a
│   ├── ab.jpg
│   └── b
│       ├── aab.jpg
│       └── c
│           ├── aaa1.jpg
│           └── aaab.jpg
├── b.JPG
├── b.jpeg
├── b.jpg
└── c1.jpg
```

Тогда результат:

```
dest
├── a
│   ├── ab.jpg
│   └── b
│       ├── aab.jpg
│       └── c
│           └── aaab.jpg
└── b.jpg
```

Перед копированием `dest` папка не должна существовать.

Если структуру директорий не нужно повторять, чтобы все файлы в одну папку скопировать:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import re
import shutil
from pathlib import Path

dest_dir = Path('dest')
dest_dir.mkdir(exist_ok=True)
for path in Path('src').rglob('*.jpg'):
    if re.fullmatch(r'\D+', path.stem):
        shutil.copy2(str(path), str(dest_dir), follow_symlinks=False)
```

В этом случае результат:

```
dest
├── aaab.jpg
├── aab.jpg
├── ab.jpg
└── b.jpg
```

Видно, что только файлы с расширением `.jpg` скопированы и только те из них, которые не имеют цифры в корне имени.

В bash этого можно достигнуть, используя `find` команду:

```
$ mkdir dest
$ find src -regex '.*/[^0-9]+\.jpg' -exec cp -a -t dest {} +
```

---

В коде в вопросе у вас как минимум проблема с использованием `os.walk()`. Эта функция генерирует триплеты: `(dirpath, dirnames, filenames)`, а не `papka` как ваш код ожидает.